# Pandas from_json gives ValueError when reading a json created by to_json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I get the following error when attempting to read in a json file that was written using DataFrame.to_json().

> ```
> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must must pass an index
> ```

The format of the json is {index: value, index: value, ...} and came from a one column dataframe.

Here is the json file on dropbox:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/md1awxetkri0nb3/pandas_json_ulines.json

The call I've tried is:

```
pd.read_json('pandas_json_ulines.json')
```

with various "orient"'s, but since I did not explicitly set the orient on the to_json call I don't think it should be necessary.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: best to show the original frame and how you saved it json, also what version pandas.

Comment: Happens in pandas 0.12 and the latest git master.  I will work on getting original frame.

Comment: Turns out it was not a DF afterall, rather a Series.  Needed to specifiy type='series' in from_json call.

Comment: How do I say solved?  Not seeing it.

Comment: gr8. I think u can post answer to your own question (u don't get rep but it becomes solved that way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was not a DF afterall, rather a Series. Needed to specifiy typ='series' in from_json call.